# should I model time variable in absolute or relative to task?

Tags: regression

Let's say I have data from one mouse as it performed three six-second tasks `x` `y` and `z`. I coded the time variable in two different ways, either as absolute time relative to the beginning of the experiment (`time1`) or as relative to each `task` (`time2`):

```r
df <- data.frame(task=rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each=6), 
       time1=rep(c(1:18)), time2=rep(c(1:6), times=3), 
       y=c(1, 5, 9, 14, 17, 29, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 29, 21, 
           18, 16, 14, 5))
```

What is the difference between these two models?

```r
mod1 <- lm(y ~ time1*task, data=df)

mod2 <- lm(y ~ time2*task, data=df)
```

If my intention is to get predictions for each `task x time`, would `mod2` be more appropriate? What would `mod1` test then?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "absolute" and "relative" times, in part because I suspect at least one of them is intended to be a *duration.*  Could you clarify what you mean, perhaps with a realistic example?

Comment: @whuber, sorry for not being clear. I meant that `time1` starts at 1 second (start of experiment) and goes until 18 seconds (end of experiment), so time is independent of task. In contrast, `time2` is relative to `task`. So I count 1 (start of task) until 6 seconds (end of task) for each `x` `y` and `z` (which together totals the 18 seconds). Is that clearer?

Comment: I edited your question to include that information.  Please check that I didn't make any errors.